# Docker push to AWS ECR hangs immediately and times out

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to push my first docker image to ECR.  I've followed the steps provided by AWS and things seem to be going smoothly until the final push which immediately times out.  Specifically, I pass my aws ecr credentials to docker and get a "login succeeded" message.  I then tag the image which also works.  pushing to the ecr repo I get no error message, just the following:

```
The push refers to repository [xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/reponame]
714c1b96dd83: Retrying in 1 second 
d2cdc77dd068: Retrying in 1 second 
30aad807caf5: Retrying in 1 second 
0559774c4ea2: Retrying in 1 second 
285b8616682f: Retrying in 1 second 
4aeea0ec2b15: Waiting 
1b1312f842d8: Waiting 
c310009e0ef3: Waiting 
a48777e566d3: Waiting 
2a0c9f28029a: Waiting 
EOF
```

It tries a bunch of times and then exits with no message.  Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Good answers below. But the causes may vary. Best to check CloudTrail

Comment: FWIW, we're in the same situation, and I found nothing in CloudTrail signifying this error.

Comment: Had the same issue. I did not create the repo first at ECR.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

I figured out my issue.  I wasn't using the correct credentials.  I had a personal AWS account as my default credentials and needed to add my work profile to my credentials.

**EDIT**
If you have multiple aws profiles, you can mention the profile name at the docker login as below (assuming you have done `aws configure --profile someprofile` at earlier day),

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 --profile someprofile | docker login ....
```

Comment: Had the same error but my problem was that the user didn't have the correct permissions.

Comment: In my case, the AWS Account has ECR permission set to * (all). But I still face the issue

Comment: Finally, I figured out the issue. There are 2 things. One is AWS Login and the other one is ECR Login. For Pull, we need to do both for the Source and for Push, we need to do both for Target account. This solved the issue. Most disappointing part is where AWS CLI doesn't say that it is an authentication issue.

Comment: I was using aws sso login and my default account did not match the one where my ECR was located.

Comment: Yeah, my confusion came from, so in Harbor I create a repo like: harbor.mydomain.com/org, then push my image which will be under .../org/image, and this works. In AWS you do not set up .../org seperately, you need to do .../org/image-name as the name of the repository. CloudTrain, suggested by Alena below this answer solved it beautifully.

Comment: Thank you, this was great clue to resolve my retrying issue. The role I was using did not have enough permissions.

Comment: My issue stems from an MFA restriction policy I set up that interrupted access to my repository.  I'm not sure if anyone has encountered this issue

Comment: In my case, the registry URL was bad. Check the accountID, the region and the repository name in the URL.

Comment: This answers solved my problem, thank you soo much.

Answer (score 116):

You will get the same behaviour if you forget to create ECR repo before pushing.

Use CloudTrail to get a clue what is wrong.

Comment: I immediately feel stupid, but at least I can now push the image xD

Comment: Thanks, looking at CloudTrail helped me fix my issue. Indeed, `docker push...` does not return useful error messages. I understand it can't return AWS ECR internal error messages, because AWS shouldn't send them back. But at least, it could have said "we got a request denied error from the repo you tried to push at - check with them please" :)

Comment: Also, you have to create the REPO as a PRIVATE REPOSITORY so the desired URI [xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/reponame] is mapped accordingly

Comment: So stupid, but even if you remember to create it, make sure you match your underscores, dashes, and stuff... can be easily overlooked.

Comment: thank you. What a brain fart.

Comment: CloudTrail ended up revealing my issue as well, good recommendation. I specifically forgot to alter an IAM Policy to give access to the image, so it was erroring out due to permissions.

Comment: Cloudtrail note was the answer; thanks for that.

Comment: Yeah using CloudTrail helps a lot, I had a "UploadLayerPart" event telling me I had the wrong naming for my ECR registry that wasn't showing anywhere else :) 
Thanks

Comment: >Use CloudTrail to get a clue what is wrong.
Thanks Man for this!

Comment: "Use CloudTrail to get a clue what is wrong" would be the correct answer for everyone. very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 52):

Make sure the name of your repository is the same name as your images.
`image:latest 756839881602.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/image:latest` in this case my repository name is `image` and my image name is `image` as well. This worked for me.

Comment: This is what got me too. Strange how the ECR repository name has to be the same as the docker image name.

Comment: a repository is for one image. The image you are pushing has to be tagged with the exact name of the repository.

Comment: This was my case, wasted so much time.

Comment: Same here - its strange that there is no feedback for this. Thankfully I checked CloudTrail, but still wasted a few hours...

Comment: This it what happented to mee too, and it is quite unintuitive for ECR "repository name" == "container image name" and that's not how docker works. `push` should be able to create images in a repo regardless its name.

Answer (score 30):

Also make sure that you have configured correct policy for your user — for example, AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess.

Comment: Just want to add that even with `ecr:*` the error on `docker push` after a successful login can be a `Retrying in x seconds`, then failing.
Adding this Managed Policy solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 18):

In my case, the repository I wanted to push to didn't exist (For example, I tried pushing to `my-app/backend:latest` but only the `my-app/cms` repository exists). So make sure your repository exists in the **AWS ECR Console** in the right region. The error returned from AWS CLI (EOF) didn't help at all.

Answer (score 17):

I have to add for anyone else encountering this problem. Go to IAM and make sure you have put permissions. I don't want to say how long I wasted before figuring that out.

Edit to help @zac's answer:
The policies that need to be attached are `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess` and `AWSAppRunnerServicePolicyForECRAccess`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I am having the same issue. In my case, the AWS Account has ECR permission set to * (all). But I still face the issue.

Comment: Finally, I figured out the issue. There are 2 things. One is AWS Login and the other one is ECR Login. For Pull, we need to do both for the Source and for Push, we need to do both for Target account. This solved the issue. Most disappointing part is where AWS CLI doesn't say that it is an authentication issue

Comment: @ven can you please elaborate more regarding AWS login and ECR login?

Answer (score 13):

In my case it was related to MFA (Multi-Factor-Authentication).
I had to create a session token. The docker login seemed to be successful, but pushing does not work.

The following script is doing all for you and creates a aws profile "mfa" used to login:  [get_mfa_credentials.py](https://gist.github.com/eilers/d8a87842e42397d5faf2c2c22ad5b243)

After executing, you can login with:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region <YOUR_REGION> --profile mfa | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <Your_REPO>
```

I do not know who wrote it, but I'm very grateful to this guy.

And thanks to AWS for bad tools that do not help.

Comment: This should be more upvoted, if you dont want any script, you can do it manually following this tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/ which is from amazon itself. After configuring the `mfa` profile just log in into docker

Comment: This doesn't work if you use a hardware security key. In my case the easiest solution was to create a new AWS user just for ECR access.

Comment: This was exactly the issue we faced, IAM role was MFA Enforced, and it was blocking the docker push to ecr, without giving any useful error message.

Thank you for providing this answer.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you authenticated successfully to AWS and you have permissions to read, write to ECR, check if the repository does exist

```
aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-name reponame
```

If you catch an error `RepositoryNotFoundException`, then you will create to that repository with the following command

```
aws ecr create-repository --repository-name reponame
```

After that, try to push again, it will be fine!

Answer (score 12):

Check your aws permissions. In addition to `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess` permission, below actions has to be granted for the correct resource. Especially check `"arn:aws:ecr:${REGION}:${ACCOUNT_ID}:repository/{$REGISTRY_NAME}"` part.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        "ecr:DescribeImages",
        "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:ListImages",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:${REGION}:${ACCOUNT_ID}:repository/{$REGISTRY_NAME}"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Giving `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess` will negate the need for the additional permissions listed here as its effect is to `Allow` the action `"ecr:*"` on resource `"*"`.

Answer (score 7):

For those who tried the solution above, and it didn't work, make sure the image name your are pushing is the same as the repository name.

Answer (score 6):

Ensure you are using the correct profile and that the repository exists

Command to login with profile: `aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> --profile=<profile-name> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

Command to create repo if it does not exists:
`aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-names ${REPO_NAME} || aws ecr create-repository --repository-name ${REPO_NAME}`([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51028677/create-aws-ecr-repository-if-it-doesnt-exist))

Comment: In my case, I misunderstood that ECR is different from repository. I used to push on GCP without creating repo. but ECR does not create automatically repository if not exists.https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/853

Answer (score 5):

I also was able to login to the registry, yet the pushing of the image would just timeout.

The solution for me was to add `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess` to my IAM user.

After adding that permission to my IAM user account, I could `docker push` to the ECS registry just fine.

Comment: PowerUser is sufficient

Answer (score 4):

The issue was resolved, when I created the docker repository first (in ECR) and then pushed it to ECR.
Remember to create the docker repository, before running the docker push command.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I misconfigured the tag name like this:

```
$ docker tag <image_name>:latest xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/reponame/<additional_string>:latest
$ docker push xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/reponame/<additional_string>:latest
...timeout...
```

And I found the <additional_string> should be deleted:

```
$ docker tag <image_name>:latest xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/reponame:latest
$ docker push xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/reponame:latest
...success!...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was experiencing.   Thanks!
ECR doesn't support sub-repo

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still stuck with the issue. I would highly recommend watching this short vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89ZeXaZEf80&ab_channel=IdenticalCloud

Here are the steps I took to fix the issue (if you prefer not to watch the video):

1. Create a new IAM user with "Access keys" checked
2. Under permissions, click on "attach existing policies directly" and choose "AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess"
3. Download the CSV file
4. Run "AWS configure" on your terminal and pass in the credentials from the CSV file
5. Set the location to the location you created your ECR (mine was us-east-1)
6. Go to ECR and follow the steps to push the image

Answer (score 1):

Please check cloud trail event logs , this is where all the api issues are clearly highlighted .

In my case it was because i had a `-` in my image name  and hence it was throwing the following error in the cloud trail logs

```
"The repository with name 'myimage-nginx' does not exist in the registry with id '516583196897'
```

Please note the `-` in the image name.

Fixing the image name to remove the `-` resolved the issue for me.

### Commands

```sh
docker tag nginx:latest 516583196897.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/myimage:latest

docker push 516583196897.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/myimage:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your assumed aws role has the ability to push images to AWS ECR. Easiest is to check the role via the command:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity --profile=saml
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to delete the stack and re-deploy the stack. Then, I was able to push the docker image to ECR.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was creating the repo in `us-east-2` and attempting to push to `us-east-1`, so docker couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I was following [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/getting-started-cli.html) and hit this error. What addressed the problem was using the repository id instead of the account name.

`aws ecs create-repository` creates a repo, returning a `repositoryUri`. Then, the `docker login`, `docker tag` and `docker push` should be done using that repository url instead of the user one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with `sam deploy`

- `sam delete --stack-name  ...`
- `sam deploy --guided`

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**Haven't found any solution?**

Maybe you are falling in the use case I had.

**identifiers:**

1. You working on different AWS accounts on the same terminal.
2. When jumping between AWS accounts, you're using `export AWS_PROFILE` (directly or via some tool or command) in the terminal level to export the profile.
3. You are able to push sometimes, and sometimes not.
4. You do manage to login with `aws ecr get-login-password`.

**What was the cause?**

When I switched between AWS accounts, although I had a valid session token for each account, BUT I forgot sometimes to `export AWS_PROFILE` back the relevant profile.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found is. Go to the console and create a repository. Click on the created repo to see the `view push commands` button. click and it will list all commands you need to build and push the image into the repo. you don't need to do any changes.

Comment: Scrolled all the way to the bottom to find the thing that works. The push commands clear up what things are called. Turns out a repo is for all the versions of one artefact, not all the versions of all the artefacts in your project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a configuration issue, aws cli was configured for my other aws account and i was trying to push my image in my mother account

Figured it out with aws configure, and changed the necessary credentials.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't specify a region in my policy:

```
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - ecr:*
  Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:ecr::${AWS::AccountId}:repository/my-image"
```

Should be:

```
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - ecr:*
  Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:ecr:eu-central-1:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/my-image"
```

Answer (score 0):

If EOF is getting printed in console after couple of retrying statements then below solution is works:

```
add permission named "AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess" to same IAM user.
add "ecr:UploadLayerPart" action in inline policy of IAM user.
```

then try:

```
docker push <ecr repo uri>
```

Above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue by using the commands

`docker tag <Image-ID> 754431986477.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/<aws repository name>:latest`

`docker push 754431986477.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/<aws repository name>:latest`

Answer (score 0):

If you think that everything is fine from docker perspective and the registry do exists and docker is able to login then, do check the policy for your registry that fits your usecase. For instance, if your docker server is in one AWS account and the registry in another AWS account, then you will need to provide a policy to your registry and vice versa.
For cross-AWS accounts, below is the solution.

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/secondary-account-access-ecr

Also a video on this,
https://youtu.be/YvqImD7pe9g