# Github actions fails when pushing docker image to ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, github-actions, amazon-ecr

I'm referring to the official github guide to set up automated deploy to ECS
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-to-your-cloud-provider/deploying-to-amazon-elastic-container-service

My deploy.yaml workflow looks identical to the one in the above link, only with the correct environment variables substituted

i've completed all the steps as required and have all the necessary infrastructure on AWS up and running.
But when the workflow get's triggered, it always fails at pushing the docker image to ECR.
After retrying for a couple of times, it exits with

```
EOF
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

From the output i can see on the github actions, I believe the login to ecr step succeeded and also can confirm that it's pushing to the right ECR repository, but for some reason the push fails.

I've already pushed images to the repository locally and it works, so I don't think anything is wrong on the AWS side of things.

Comment: Can you paste the workflow file and build logs as well? (Remove private details)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I realized my own mistake with this.
In the environment file where i'm supposed to specify the repository-name i had instead specified the full repository ID
meaning if the repository is named my-ecr-repo, i had instead accidentally written .dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-ecr-repo
setting the name to just my-ecr-repo solved the problem

Comment: ran into the same issue. Was easy to miss :) thanks!

Answer (score 7):

While logging into AWS account using the aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1, I was specifying wrong aws-region.

AWS region should be same as the ecr repo region. Else, even if login is successful, push will fail.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. Saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70452836/docker-push-to-aws-ecr-hangs-immediately-and-times-out) that you can lookup the logs for this issue in Cloudtrail. After doing so I saw that my user was missing the `ecr:InitiateLayerUpload` action. After updating my user I was able to push to ECR

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's save my day! Thanks Jósúa!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when my IAM user did not have sufficient permissions to write to the repository. My updated permissions were as follows, which worked.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:PutImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem, but what I found that, the ECR repo where I was trying to push doesn't exist. I deleted the repo for some testing purpose and forgot to re-create and trying docker push and it was failing like below :

f9cb3f1f1d3d: Retrying in 1 second

**EOF**

**Error: Process completed with exit code 1.**

I re-created the ECR repo and able to do docker push successfully.